Trigger several releases from the same build
I'm working with Azure DevOps CI/CD and Logic Apps.
In the build, I managed to extract which Logic Apps were modified and save the list in a .txt that I added to the artifact.
I'd like to trigger several releases based on the entries of this list, i.e. a new release for each Logic App that was modified. Can that be done ? If yes, should I:

do that in the build and trigger the releases from there
do that in the release and trigger deployments there

Aside from helping me take the right decision, any further help in how to actually write the loop for triggering the releases would be great help :)
I'm awaiting an approval for Trigger Azure DevOps Pipeline so that I can try that, but other than that I don't know where to start to trigger multiple releases from the same build.

My first thought is to make a separate release that triggers from the successful build, which then uses the DevOps API to trigger the individual releases.

@juunas pardon my ignorance, but how would you trigger several releases in the release ? Is there a way to loop ? That's where I'm stuck right now.

I don't have a sample to give you but I'd probably use a script that goes over the output of the build and calls this endpoint for each build: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/queue?view=azure-devops-rest-7.2

As an alternative to the REST API you can use Azure DevOps CLI command az pipelines build queue: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/pipelines/build?view=azure-cli-latest#az-pipelines-build-queue


I'd like to trigger several releases based on the entries of this list, i.e. a new release for each Logic App that was modified. Can that be done ? If yes, should I: do that in the build and trigger the releases from there? do that in the release and trigger deployments there?

Yes, it can be done. Since you already have the txt in build, the better way is to do above steps in build, to trigger each releases.
Actually there are two main steps:

parse the txt file, create the loop based on entry in the list.

In the loop, trigger the release pipeline.


There are many ways to trigger the releases from build, for example(not all):

Releases - Create rest api
az pipelines release CLI
Extension tasks, eg: TriggerPipeline@2
Release triggers

If you create the release with Yaml not classic editor, you can use all build trigger method, it's more.
You should choose the best way according to your real situation. For example, if you would like to trigger the release and transfer variable value to be used, you can use rest api above.
As i don't have your txt file content, let's assume to trigger release for each line in ModifiedLogicApps.txt for a sample.
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- powershell: |
    $modifiedLogicApps = Get-Content -Path ModifiedLogicApps.txt

    # Loop through each Logic App and trigger a release
    foreach ($logicApp in $modifiedLogicApps) {
        Write-Host "Triggering release for Logic App: $logicApp"

        # Set your Azure DevOps Personal Access Token (PAT)
        $token = "$(PAT)"

        # Convert the token to base64
        $token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))

        # Define the release pipeline definition ID
        $definitionId = 2  # Replace with your actual release pipeline definition ID

        # Define any additional variables you want to pass and create the release payload
        $releasePayload = @{
            definitionId = $definitionId
            variables = @{
                logicapp = @{
                    value = $logicApp
                }
            }
        }

        # Convert the payload to JSON
        $releasePayloadJson = $releasePayload | ConvertTo-Json

        # Define the REST API URL for creating a release
        $apiUrl = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/$(orgname)/$(project)/_apis/release/releases?api-version=7.1-preview.8"

        echo $apiUrl      # check url

        # Invoke the REST API to trigger the release
        Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $apiUrl -Method Post -Body $releasePayloadJson -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"}
      }


In your release pipeline, please predefined the variable and choose settable at release time.

I will output the $(logicapp) value in release for check:

After build, each logic app will create a new release run:

And it has the variable value output, different in each release.


This helps a lot, thanks ! I'm getting this message, though: Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. Since yours worked, is this kind of authorisation something you can set in your Azure DevOps ?

The 401 error indicates the token is not correct. In my script sample, i used PAT for authorization. Please make sure the account(which used to create PAT) has create release and Edit release pipeline on the target release. You can simply login with the account, try to trigger the release(set variable value meanwhile) to validate the account permission. If it's OK, try to regenerate the PAT and update in the script for a check. When you create the PAT, make sure the organization is correct. If the error persists, please share the error details for further investigation.

I was using an old PAT that didn't have the access, I generated a new one with full access and now it works ! Thank you so much for the great help :)

Glad to know it helps! Happy coding!
